# Is there a relation between density of states (DOS) and carrier mobility in semiconductors?

Tags: electrons, semiconductor-physics, density-of-states

By changing DOS, mobility how to change?

What is the relationship between DOS and mobility, if there is?

Answer (score 1):

There is no relationship. Mobilities depend on temperature, the DOS does not. Mobilities in semiconductors and in good metals are of about the same order of magnitude.